# file-gallery plugin line 1573 broken in 4.2 upgrade

Tags: plugins, upgrade

This plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-gallery/ seems to be broken on upgrading to wordpress 4.2, here is the error I am getting.

```
[function.require]: Failed opening required 'includes/templates-media-wp42.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/85/9609685/html/wp-content/plugins/file-gallery/file-gallery.php on line 1573
```

I also posted to the file-gallery plugin page as broken

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/file-galleryphp-line-1573-broken-in-42?replies=1#post-6862023

Answer (score -1):

I ended up duplicated /includes/templates-media-wp41.php and renaming it to templates/media-wp42.php